# Can't read Com port with QB64

Tags: port, qb64

I am using Arduino as a slave just to read the voltage of a battery.
The program in Arduino is is C. The computer program is written in QB64
It is connected to a USB com port#3. The slave program and QB64 work fine for making the Pin 13 Blink. But when I ask for a voltage all I get is 10 empty spaces no data.
The following QB64 code is my attempt to read. The comments show some of the results:

```
CLS
ctr = 1 '                           Counts number times you press continue

again:
INPUT "Press any key to continue"; d$ ' Run program to receive voltage 
OPEN "Com3:9600,n,8,1,ds0,cs0,rs" FOR RANDOM AS #1
_DELAY .5 '                                      delay to let com settle
FIELD #1, 35 AS m$

'            ****  Form Message to send to External Device ****
Command = 2: pin = 4: argument = 0 '   Code to Get analog voltage reading
msg$ = STR$(Command) + "," + STR$(pin) + "," + STR$(argument) + "*"
PRINT "msg$ Sent= "; msg$, CHR$(13) '                     Show Message
LSET m$ = msg$
PUT #1, , m$ '                  Send message to the external device
_DELAY 1


'*****  C code in external device  *****
'External device responds to message & prints to Com3 buffer.
' if ( cmd == 2)//getanalog
'   {
'        int sensorValue = analogRead(pin);//
'        delay(10);
'        float voltage= sensorValue*(5.0/1023.0);
'        Serial.print("Voltage =");
'        Serial.print(voltage);
'        Serial.print(",");
'       Serial.print("*");
'      }

CLOSE #1

m$ = "": msg$ = "" '                            Wipe out old messages

OPEN "Com3:9600,n,8,1,ds0,cs0,rs" FOR RANDOM AS #1
_DELAY .5 '                                    Delay to let Com Port settle
FIELD #1, 50 AS m$

t1 = TIMER '                                     Start time for getdata

getdata:
bytes% = LOC(1) '                             Check receive buffer for data
IF bytes% = 0 THEN GOTO getdata 'After thousands of cycles it continues
PRINT "Bytes="; bytes '                           Bytes remain at 0
DO UNTIL EOF(1)
    GET #1, , m$ '                         First GET #1 returns EOF=-1
    PRINT "LEN(m$)= "; LEN(m$) '               Length of m$ = 10
    IF INSTR(m$, "*") > 0 THEN GOTO duh '    Never finds End of Message (*)
LOOP

IF bytes% = 0 THEN GOTO getdata
t2 = TIMER '                                         End time, Have data
DeltaT = t2 - t1 '                                   How long did it take?
GOTO stepover '               If arrived here w/o End of Message signal

duh:
PRINT "DUH instr= "; INSTR(m$, "*") '               Never hits this line
stepover:

tmp$ = "DeltaT= #.### Seconds Until LOC(1) > 0" '   Various times 
PRINT USING tmp$; DeltaT
PRINT "m$ Received= "; m$ + "&" '                 Prints 10 spaces No Data
PRINT "endofdata= "; endofdata '                endofdata=0, Never got "*"
PRINT "ctr= "; ctr, CHR$(13) '    Show number of times you pressed continue
CLOSE #1
ctr = ctr + 1
GOTO again
```

Also included in the comments is the Slave program that writes to the com port.
Some lines of QB64 code are not necessary but were included as debugging attempt

Comment: Are you sure you want `RANDOM` and not `INPUT` or `BINARY`? Also: _Optional COM port Options (separated by commas): `ASC`: ASCII byte mode. End of line = `CHR$(13)`. End of file = `CHR$(26)`. `BIN`: Binary byte mode. Default mode if `ASC` is not used(option not required)._ Not sure of the format of the data you send, and I've never used Arduino or serial communications, so I can't really say one way or another what you need to do, but I hope this helps a little. Got my info from [the QB64 Wiki](http://www.qb64.net/wiki/index.php/OPEN_COM).

Comment: This program works but does not require reading of the com port by the computer.Tried to post Blink program but too long here.

Comment: Random with put commands work fine for output to Com port and can control the on board LED

Comment: An output data command format example: 4, 13, 0* This command which works parses as 4= set digital output, 13= set digital pin 13, 0 = Low or onboard LED to off, asterisk = end of the message. 4, 13,1* will turn on the LED. These commands work. The command 2, 4, 0* says do an A/D input on analog pin 4 then print results to com port ending with an Asterisk indicating end of serial message.

Comment: The section of Arduino code responding to command 2,4,0*   Should be                                  
        if ( cmd == 2)//  ******  GET ANALOG  ******
      {
       int sensorValue = analogRead(pin);      
        delay(10);
       float voltage= sensorValue*(5.0/1023.0);
        Serial.print("Voltage =");
        Serial.print(pin);
        Serial.print(voltage);
        Serial.print(",");
        //Serial.print(sensorValue);//(analogRead(pin)) replaced with (sensorValue)
        //Serial.print(analogRead(pin));
        Serial.print("*");
      }

Comment: From what I can see, it should work fine. It seems, however, like QB64 is having trouble reading from the serial port for some reason. If you add Serial.flush(); after Serial.print("*"); does the Arduino wait indefinitely for the buffer to be read? Of course, I'm assuming you can just unplug its power source to reset it without harming the device, else `Serial.flush()` would make the Arduino hang forever unless you used a C program to read the data if QB64 couldn't.

Comment: I added some code to blink the LED to let me know that the C program was indeed parsing the command message correctly, and it did. I added the serial.flush(); command and it made no difference.

Comment: I have revised my QB64 Code as follows. The main problem seems to be that as soon as I open the Com Port EOF goes to -1 and LOF and LOC =0

Comment: Code to read Com Port  ‘ ** Wipe out old mesages
Z$ = ""

OPEN "Com3:9600,n,8,1,ds0,cs0,rs" FOR INPUT AS #2
_DELAY .25 '                                       Delay to let Com Port settle

PRINT "EOF="; EOF(2), "LOC="; LOC(2), "LOF="; LOF(2) '                            

DO UNTIL INSTR(Z$, "*") > 0
    Z$ = INPUT$(12, # 2) 
    PRINT "EOF(2)="; EOF(2)
LOOP

PRINT "instr="; INSTR(Z$, "*")

PRINT "Z$="; Z$ ,”   lenZ$= “; LEN(Z$)

EOF is always -1 which messes up INPUT statement. How can I made QB64 sense the information in the Com Port? Message in the buffer is Voltage = 1.2, *

Comment: Can you verify that a simple QB64 program can both read and write to the COM port, like [the `LOC` example from the QB64 wiki](http://www.qb64.net/wiki/index.php/LOC)? There shouldn't be any C code necessary for that program to work as intended. All you need to do is type some characters and wait for them to be echoed back to your screen from the COM port. You might need to adjust the communication parameters in the `OPEN` statement and add a `1` in the `CLOSE` statement at the end, but those should be the only things you need to change to get the test working.

Comment: The first statement OPEN gives me a "Bad File Name" error. I ran the Does Com port exist program and only Com Port 3 exists, others give Error 68     OPEN "COM3: 9600,N,8,1,OP0" FOR RANDOM AS #1 
DO: t$ = INKEY$ ' get any transmit keypresses from user
    IF LEN(t$) THEN PRINT #1, t$ ' send keyboard byte to transmit buffer
    bytes% = LOC(1) ' bytes in buffer
    IF bytes% THEN ' check receive buffer for data"
        r$ = INPUT$(bytes%, 1) ' get bytes in the receive buffer
        PRINT r$; ' print byte strings consecutively to screen"
    END IF
LOOP UNTIL t$ = CHR$(27) 
CLOSE #1

Comment: When I removed the space between the colon and 9600 it fixed that error, but then I discovered that PRINT can't be used with FOR RANDOM. I get a bad file mode error.  I need to use PUT# if it opened with FOR RANDOM.

Comment: OK, once you've fixed everything and use `FOR RANDOM` with `PUT#` and `GET#`, does it work? Can you press keys, and it'll send and receive the keys you press, echoing them back to the screen?

Comment: Still doesn't work I get the same thing where EOF =0  and LOF and LOC =0. Since LOC=0 it is stuck in the BYtes%=LOC' IF bytes THEN loop.

Comment: If you use OPEN FOR RANDOM then LOF is automatically set to 0 which causes the GET statement to fail with BAD Record Length. If you try to use OPEN FOR INPUT then EOF is automatically set to -1 which causes the INPUT statement to fail with INPUT PAST END OF FILE.Until these issues are solved QB64 can't be used to read a Com Port Buffer.

Comment: SOLUTION I found a Work Around for the EOF=-1 problem. I opened with For INPUT and used the command Z$=input(LOF(2),#2) to read the port. This always gives an INPUT PAST END OF FILE error. So immediately before that line I added ON ERROR GOTO EHandler. Then at the end of the program I added EHandler: with the next two lines being 
errfile$ = _INCLERRORFILE$
RESUME NEXT
It took Weeks for me to figure this work around out. If you have this problem and read this maybe it will work for you w/o taking so long.